# Does the population variance equal the variance of a single observation?

Tags: statistics, variance, hypothesis-testing, means

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error), the standard error $\sigma^-_x$ of a sample mean can be computed by $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of a statistical population and $n$ is the number of observations in the sample.

In the derivation of this equation follows from the variance of the sum of independent random variables. That is, if $x_1, x_2, ...$ are $n$ independent observations from a population with mean $\overline{x}$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, we can define
$$T = (x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n),$$
which gives $\mathrm{Var}(T) = (\mathrm{Var}(x_1) + \mathrm{Var}(x_2) + ...+ \mathrm{Var}(x_n)) = n*\sigma^2$.

What confuses me is the result $n*\sigma^2$. I thought that $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation and not the deviation of a single observation? That is, I thought, a population with only one observation should have $\sigma=0?$

Furthermore, $Var(T/n) = \frac{1}{n^2} Var(t)$ - why $n^2$ ??

Comment: Suppose you are observing the moods of people on a particular day. It is not certain what mood your first subject will be in. There is rather a probability distribution over their moods which itself has a variance. That's $\sigma^2$. The sum of moods (okay, I guess you'd have to quantify mood but ignore that), has its own distribution, and its variance is $n\sigma^2$. This is what we're interested in estimating by taking the sample variance. You're looking at the same notation used for different things, probably by different authors.

Comment: so you say is that what confuses me here is that the authors assumes that all of the observation themself have the same standard deviation $\sigma$ and therefore the population, consisted of all these obeservation, also have a standard deviation of $\sigma$

Comment: However, why

`c <- rnorm(100000, 0, 1)

c <- c(c,  rnorm(100000, 0, 2))
c <- c(c,  rnorm(100000, 0, 3))

mean(c) # 0.002163284
sd(c) # 2.162891`  does then  not produce a standard deviation of `c` of 2? I mean the population should be high enough i guess

Comment: $Var(kT)=k^2 Var(T)$: you have scaled by a factor of $k$ so you scale squares by $k^2$.  In your final question $k=\frac1n$.  Meanwhile if $T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_n$ are independent then  $Var(T_1+T_2+\cdots+T_n)= Var(T_1)+Var(T_2)+\cdots+Var(T_n)$